# Import an organised table from excel in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have an excel table with 6 rows and 31 columns and i want to import it to my jsf page. I succeeded to display it in order in the console but i couldn't find a way to do the same in my jsf page.

This is the code:

```
public void showfile() throws FileNotFoundException,IOException{

    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\tahab_000\\Desktop\\Test.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    for(Row row: sheet){
        for(Cell cell: row){
            switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"\t\t");
                s1=s1+cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t\t");
                s1=s1+cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can define a Class named `Foo` which has same properties as your excel file do. Then instead of writing to the console you can instantiate an object of `Foo` class and add it to a `List`. Finally you can use jsf to show values in the `List` using some  code like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{beanName.yourList} ..../>"
```

the following like might help you to how to show a data with jsf:
https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/